# How to view vtable for C++ class in LLDB?

Tags: c++, lldb

I'd like to see virtual function tables for C++ classes using LLDB. 
This seems to be possible for GDB but I can't find any docs explaining how to do the same for LLDB.

Comment: did you try to seach the internet? [this](http://artagnon.com/inspecting-vtables-with-lldb/) is the first thing I found

Comment: @tobi303 I did search but must have missed that. If you post it as an answer I'll happily accept.

Comment: Link is no longer active; wayback machine archived version: [https://web.archive.org/web/20161013190159/https://artagnon.com/inspecting-vtables-with-lldb/](https://web.archive.org/web/20161013190159/https://artagnon.com/inspecting-vtables-with-lldb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported in lldb.  There is a bug requesting the feature.

Answer (score 1):

@tobi303 gave a link that showed:

`image lookup -r -v -s "vtable for YOUR_CLASS_NAME`

would give some info about the vtable.

Jim Inham's answer above remains accepted.